# Does POSIX define the behavior when sending NUL to terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, posix

Here is a Perl program that sends ASCII NUL as output:

```
print "hello\0world"
```

And here is how to run such a program from `sh` or `bash`:

```
perl -e 'print "hello\0world"'
```

On Mac OS X 10.11.2, this produces the visible output:

```
helloworld
```

However, is this behavior consistent for all POSIX-compliant terminal emulators? (As opposed to, for example, printing NUL as a new line, or crashing?)

Comment: You should add that to your question and delete the comment.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks, done

Comment: POSIX doesn't standardize terminal emulators, only shells. (Well, it standardizes other things, but the behavior here is governed by the terminal emulator, which is not covered by POSIX.)

Comment: BTW, `printf 'hello\0world\n` is a somewhat easier way to repro from bash.

Comment: Wow. I Googled "posix nul to terminal" and your question is the first thing that came up. I guess that means you are caught in an infinite loop until someone brings in knowledge from outside of Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not guaranteed; as chepner noted in a comment on the question, the POSIX specification does not define terminal emulator behavior. There *does exist* a standard terminal protocol, [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm), but modern operating systems uniformly support a wide variety of terminal protocols beyond the one defined by the standard.

Some terminals print any character the local font provides for the codepoint (and `U+0000` *is* a valid codepoint).

---

Incidentally, the ECMA-48 terminal standard (used for ANSI terminals -- and again, not all terminals are *required* to be ANSI-compliant) says the following about the NUL character:

> 8.3.88 NUL - NULL
>   Notation: (C0)
>   Representation: 00/00
>
> NUL is used for media-fill or time-fill. NUL characters may be inserted into, or removed from, a data
>   stream without affecting the information content of that stream, but such action may affect the
>   information layout and/or the control of equipment.

Thus, **for an ANSI terminal**, printing a blank space for a NUL is the standards-compliant action (allowing NULs to be used to fill buffers without modifying content), but no terminal type which does not claim to comply with ECMA-48 is required to behave that same way.

Comment: It could just be that the font you were using on the terminal did not have a representation of `\0` and printed the 16-bit code instead. That is fairly common. In that case you could create a font that had something cool for `\0`, like the unicode "reboot -n" character or something.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I did and do believe that's what was happening, but initially considered it an implementation detail not necessarily germane to the answer. On consideration, I've edited appropriately.

Comment: Given your new answer, I guess OP's font was printing a zero-width something-or-other for `\0`. That's actually a pretty sensible representation.

Comment: Nice; I suggest you also incorporate your comment on the question (re POSIX not covering terminal emulators) into your answer.

Comment: @mklement0, it's chepner who made that (pertinent and accurate) observation, but it is indeed worth folding in. :)

Comment: @mklement0, ...amended appropriately, with some details on what standardization *is* available on the subject and what it has to say.

Comment: I appreciate the update; do you know how the POSIX [General Terminal Interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11) fits into all this?

Comment: @mklement0, I'd argue that it doesn't, mostly -- it defines transport-layer more than display-layer, though there is indeed some overlap.